# How to return multiple values from stored procedure to .NET?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure need to return 5 different values and want to use those value in .NET.
Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_NAME
(
  @COUNT INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE NAME1 AS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE NAME2 AS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE NAME3 AS VARCHAR(100)

    SET @NAME1 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE1 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
    SET @NAME2 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE2 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
    SET @NAME3 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE3 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
     
    SELECT @NAME1
    SELECT @NAME2
    SELECT @NAME3
END
```

Now at .NET, I know ExecuteDataset function can use to retrieve multiple data, but I don't know how to get into three different variables as stored procedure returning 3 different output.
Desired output I need is .NET variables store values from sp.

If someone knows, please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Microsoft Sql server

Comment: I mean. You could use a dataset when you're calling the proc and fill that OR a quick thing would be simply return the three variables as one table with three columns and map it to an object?

Comment: Either use a single select statement to return all three as a result set or setup output parameters for each value you want returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_NAME
  @COUNT INT,
  @NAME1 VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
  @NAME2 VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
  @NAME3 VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
        SET @NAME1 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE1 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
        SET @NAME2 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE2 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
        SET @NAME3 = (SELECT DRIVER FROM TABLE3 WHERE @COUNT = 10)
    
END
```

Comment: Possibly add how OP can get this response in asp.net

Comment: Could just do one big `SELECT`, no point querying the table multiple times